# How to send Retrofit2 request to api hosted with docker?

Tags: android, docker, httprequest

I recently switched to using docker for the development environment. I am currently developing a web app and a mobile app in android. What I fail to understand is why all my requests from android to docker are now failing: `Unable to resolve host "api.test.local": No address associated with hostname`. Even though if I try the same request with postman it works.

Any idea/ advice? Thank you all for your time!

Comment: Device is not able to resolve host api.test.local. Use IP instead.

Comment: @Héctor The docker container's api?

Comment: Use your host machine's IP and the docker container's port

Comment: @Héctor         <h1>503 Service Unavailable</h1>
No server is available to handle this request.